Race condition using FastAPI, SQLAlchemy and Asyncpg
I am currently having problems solving an issue with writing data in the postgres db due to a race condition.
Basically, I need to insert into the database a "Medico" if it doesn't exists.
However, when doing load tests, I noticed that threads are trying to insert the same values at the same time, throwing errors.
In this method, it first should look for a Medico. If it doesn't find, it creates it. The issue lies when two or more threads try to access it at the same time, and then try to save it multiple times to the database.
async def busca_cria_medico(self, venda_medico: dict) -> MedicoModel:
        """
        Verificando a existência do médico. Caso não exista, cria.
        """
        medico_existente = await self.db.execute(
            select(MedicoModel)
            .filter(MedicoModel.numero_registro == venda_medico.numero_registro,
                    MedicoModel.sigla_conselho == venda_medico.sigla_conselho, 
                    MedicoModel.uf == venda_medico.uf)
            .with_for_update()
        )
        
        medico_existente = medico_existente.scalars().first()

        if medico_existente is None:
            novo_medico = MedicoModel(nome=venda_medico.nome, numero_registro=venda_medico.numero_registro, uf=venda_medico.uf, sigla_conselho=venda_medico.sigla_conselho)
            self.db.add(novo_medico)
            await self.db.flush()
        
            return novo_medico

        return medico_existente

This is how I'm calling the function
async with self.db.begin_nested():
    medico = await self.busca_cria_medico(venda.medico)

Here is my connection
engine = create_async_engine(URL, pool_size=40, pool_timeout=30)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine, class_=AsyncSession)

How I get my db session
async def get_db():
    async with SessionLocal() as db:
        try:
            yield db
        finally:
            await db.close()

And this is the route handler
@router.post('/realizar-venda', status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def realiza_venda(venda: RealizarVenda, request: Request, db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)):
    token = request.headers.get('Authorization').split(' ')[1]
    venda_service = VendaService(db=db)
    await venda_service.realiza_venda(venda=venda, token=token)


I haven't gone through your code in detail, but to actually save your data, you should call self.db.commit() at some point.

I'm saving it after. The problem being that when I get two or more async requests, they both can't find a instance of Medico, so they both try to save it, throwing IntegrityError.

Probably the easiest solution is to not bother checking for an existing entry: Just wrap the .flush() (and/or .commit()) in a try / except block, catch the IntegrityError, log it, and carry on.

Yep. For now I'm just returning a "Try again" when the IntegrityError is thrown.
